# PHP-FPM does not automatically start after reboot

Tags: linux, nginx, php-fpm, init.d, amazon-linux

I'm running PHP-FPM and Nginx, occasionally, for whatever reason, I have to reboot the server. Once the server is running again, the nginx service automatically starts, however, PHP-FPM does not. This can be seen when I run the command `sudo /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart` immediately after a reboot and get the result:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
Stopping php-fpm:                                          [FAILED]
Starting php-fpm:                                          [  OK  ]
```

Is this expected behaviour? What is the best way to make PHP-FPM automatically start? Is there a config option anywhere, or do I have to add the command to one of the Linux startup scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: Which linux distribution are you using?  How did you installed php-fpm?  From a package or from sources?

Comment: It's running on an Amazon EC2 Linux instance, PHP-FPM was installed using `yum install -y php-fpm`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So set it up to start at boot:

```
chkconfig php-fpm on
```

Comment: As simple as that, brilliant! Cheers

Comment: `bash: chkconfig: command not found`

Comment: Solution for `chkconfig: command not found`: `update-rc.d php-fpm enable`  (you may need to specify the specific fpm, like `php8.3-fpm`). https://stackoverflow.com/a/23708174/4249483

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this very problem on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm leaving my answer here for future users from Google who stumble onto the problem.  Since `chkconfig` is mostly specific to CentOS, it obviously doesn't exist on Ubuntu.  Apparently, to get a custom-built PHP (`php-fpm` SAPI) to start at boot under `systemd`, which is new to Ubuntu 16.04 (previously, Upstart), it needs to be registered with the system beyond just dropping the `init.d` script into `/etc/init.d/`.  To register the script, I ran:

```
update-rc.d php-fpm defaults
```

A `reboot` and subsequent `ps aux` confirmed that `php-fpm` was indeed starting at boot.  It was also added to `/etc/init.d/.depend.start`.

Other thoughts:  Ubuntu Upstart was nice enough so that I never had to run `update-rc.d` after placing an init.d script - it just worked.  Completely forgot about that command.

Comment: The original question being about Amazon Linux, I can't say how many Ubuntu users will see it. As for 16.04 and systemd, the thing to do is use a proper systemd unit rather than the old-style upstart or ancient init script. You ought to be able to find a usable systemd unit with the distro package, or elsewhere.

Comment: I'm a Ubuntu 14.04 user and this helped me, thank you! PS: `sudo` might be needed for that command.

Comment: If you get an error regarding `auoms is broken` -- update the init info block in `/etc/init.d/auoms` per this release: https://github.com/microsoft/OMS-Auditd-Plugin/pull/62

Answer (score 5):

Since CentOS 7 you simply need to enable the services via systemctl:

```
systemctl enable php-fpm
```

You can check if it's running afterwards via:

```
systemctl status php-fpm
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add some commands to the `.bashrc` startup script:

Open `.bashrc`:

```
nano .bashrc
```

Paste some command to be run at startup:

(check which commands work for you)

```bash
# Start fpm-services
sudo /etc/init.d/php-fpm start
sudo /etc/init.d/php8.3-fpm start
sudo /etc/init.d/php8.2-fpm start
sudo /etc/init.d/php8.1-fpm start
sudo /etc/init.d/php8.0-fpm start
sudo /etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm start
```

Comment: this will only start the services after user login. If you really still have ancient init.d scripts the [answer by CubicleSoft](https://serverfault.com/a/785977/38644) is the proper way.